# How to create dynamic content from two json using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I've to build something like this:

[image]

There are two `JSON` files. One is for `left-col` & another is for `right-col`

`JSON` for `left-col`: http://maqe.github.io/json/posts.json

`JSON` for `right-col`: http://maqe.github.io/json/authors.json

HTML structure is something like this:

```
<div class="list-container'>
   <!-- repeat div start -->
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
      <!-- data from 1st JSON -->
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
      <!-- data from 2nd JSON -->
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- repeat div end -->
</div>
```

As everything inside `.list-container` will be generated running loop into the JSON files, final HTML will be:

```
<div class="list-container'></div>
```

I am able to create dynamic content from `1st JSON` file for `left-col (col-sm-8)`:

```
       $.getJSON('http://maqe.github.io/json/posts.json', function(data) {
            var tmp = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {

                tmp += '<div class="row">';
                tmp += '   <div class="col-sm-8">';
                tmp += '      <h3>' + element.title + '</h3>';
                tmp += '      <p>' + element.body + '</p>';
                tmp += '   </div>';
                tmp += '</div>';
            });
            $('.list-container').prepend(tmp);
        });
```

I am also able to populate content from `2nd JSON` file separately:

```
      $.getJSON('http://maqe.github.io/json/authors.json', function(data) {
            var tmp = '';
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {

                tmp += '<div class="row">';
                tmp += '   <div class="col-sm-4">';
                tmp += '      <p>'+element.name+'</p>';
                tmp += '      <p>'+element.role+'</p>';
                tmp += '   </div>';
                tmp += '</div>';
            });
            $('.list-container').prepend(tmp);
        });
```

But, I don't understand how to merge this two `$.getJSON`, so that one will go inside `left-col (col-sm-8)` and another will go inside `right-col (col-sm-4)`. Can you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Do you want to send only one ajax call?

Comment: @karthick, I got the solution from Rojen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row is being created on every loop in `$.each()`. You need to create a row and insert the columns inside the row.

```
<div class="list-container">
   <div class="row">

   </div>
</div>
```

Send the second ajax request after success of first ajax request. Add the response of the first ajax to the html by `$('.row').append()`.

and on second ajax request get each column i.e `col-sm-8` and add the response of the second ajax after that column using `$('.content:eq(' + index + ')').after(tmp);`.

Note that I added the class `.content` to `col-sm-8`

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://maqe.github.io/json/posts.json',
    tye: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var tmp = '';
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            tmp += '   <div class="col-sm-8 content">';
            tmp += '      <h3>' + element.title + '</h3>';
            tmp += '      <p>' + element.body + '</p>';
            tmp += '   </div>';
        });
        $('.row').append(tmp);
        secondAjaxCall();
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});

function secondAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://maqe.github.io/json/authors.json',
        tye: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                var tmp = '';
                tmp += '   <div class="col-sm-4">';
                tmp += '<img src="' + element.avatar_url + '">';
                tmp += '      <p>' + element.name + '</p>';
                tmp += '      <p>' + element.role + '</p>';
                tmp += '   </div>';

                $('.content:eq(' + index + ')').after(tmp);
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }

    });
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/889516/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help!